# Decompile React Native index.android.bundle

Tags: android, react-native, obfuscation

I am using React Native and integrated library [react-native-obfuscating-transformer](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/react-native-obfuscating-transformer)
to obfuscate my code. Now after decompiling my APK, I believe my whole js code is under **assets/index.android.bundle**.

How can I debundle it and see my code whether obfuscation worked or not.

Comment: This question should belong to: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 27):

#### For Macbook

```
brew install apktool
```

after install `apktool`, unzip apk file by run this command on terminal like this:

```
apktool  d /pathOfApkFile.apk
```

After that you will get `index.android.bundle` file at `pathOfApkFile/assets/index.android.bundle`

than you can use [react-native-decompiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-decompiler) for decompile `index.android.bundle` file

### Decompile `index.android.bundle` File

you can decompile `index.android.bundle` by run this command

```
npx react-native-decompiler -i ./index.android.bundle -o ./output
```

after that, you will get **JS decompiled file** in `./output` directory

## JS Code Decompile

React Native is already doing uglify js code.

and **react-native-obfuscating-transformer** is also make complex uglifying code

It is something like MD5 and SHA256 encryption and there is no the tool available right know when make machine learning and bruteforce to give us estimated code

**If you want to varify react-native-obfuscating-transformer is implemented or not then you can edit index.android.bundle and save code then implement react-native-obfuscating-transformer and edit and compare both file**

you can make more uglify code by adding flag in build.gradle called `bundleInRelease: true` and add [Hermes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-decompiler) which turns js bundle to bytecode for efficiency

[REF](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/obfuscation-or-encryption-the-android-bundlejs-file)

**Note:** There is no way to decompile `index.android.bundle` because this file contains uglify code which has many reverses possible of one line

## Java Code Decompile

you can use [DEX2JAR](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/) to convert apk to java code
and you can view that code from [JD-GUI](http://java-decompiler.github.io/#jd-gui-download)

you can see this [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RL-r4GTzesk)

Comment: Hi @Muhammad, thanks for your answer. I was able to do it. But my question is different. How can debundle assets/index.android.bundle file

Comment: @FaisalAhmed I have edited my answer for index.android.bundle

Comment: It seems https://github.com/nomi9995/react-native-decompiler has been taken down. Where to find it?

Comment: use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-decompiler/v/0.2.2
V0.2.2 is working fine, > 0.2.2 is not working

Answer (score 2):

See https://android.jlelse.eu/getting-inside-apk-files-21dbd01529d4 :

> If your app is written on React Native, using the same apktool you can find index.android.bundle file inside assets folder of decompiled APK folder.
> To open it using IntelliJ IDEA, right click on the file, Associate with File Type… and choose JavaScript. And it is usual minified .js file.

In other words, opening the .bundle file in an IDE such as Intellij will yield a minified .js file, which can then be formatted and compared with your source code. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called `APK Easy Tool` download it from [here](https://www.filehorse.com/download-apk-easy-tool/download/), install it, and open it. 
[image]

Select apk by choosing browse option and click on Extract apk, when it is extrcted click on decompiled apk directory, and open directory. you would see something like this

[image]


navigate inside Extracted APKs directory you would get the bundle.


[image]