# Can't decompile React Native android apk

Tags: android, react-native, reverse-engineering

I m trying to decompile React Native apk and preferably decompile bundle.js as well with project structure, package.json and js code.

I've tried to follow these steps from here:
[Decompile React Native index.android.bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62448205/decompile-react-native-index-android-bundle/62553537#62553537)

But after this command: `apktool  d /pathOfApkFile.apk`
I don't have `index.android.bundle`

All I have is a bundle.js file in app folder.

I've tried to use debundle package from npm [debundle](https://github.com/1egoman/debundle) to debundle bundle.js but couldn't succeed as well

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you can add more specific things what do you want with decompiled application, it will be more easier to understand the question.

Comment: I just want the source code the way it was written originally, components and project structure.

Comment: Did you build this app?

Comment: yes, I am not trying to hack anybody's app.
My purpose is to learn and make my apps more secure.
So if you can help me to become a better programmer I would appreciate it